# Finding 3 abelian groups of order 64

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

Let $G$ a finit group. We define the *exposant of G* as the smallest integer $m > 0$ such that $ \forall g \in G : g^m = e$.

Two questions are asked :

1. Show that the exposant of G divide $\vert G \vert$.
2. Find 3 abelian groups non isomorphic of order 64 and exposant 8.

For the first question I showed that the group $<g>$, the group generated by $g$, was a subgroup of $G$ of order $m$. Thus by Lagrange's theorem we know that $m$ divides  $\vert G \vert$.

Comment: Do you know the **fundamental theorem of finite(ly generated) abelian groups**? (Some times called _the structure theorem of finite(ly generated) abelian groups_ instead.) It tells you (almost) everything you will ever need to know about all finite and finitely generated abelian groups.

Comment: @Arthur While I was reading *Abstract Algebra* by Dummit-Foote, I found that the **fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian groups** would be the solution to my problem. Since $64 = 2^6$, 3 partitions of 6 are $3,1,2$ ; $3,3$ ; $3,1,1,1$. 

Does it mean that, for example, one my abelian groups is Z/8Z x Z/8Z ?

Comment: Yes, that's one of the groups, corresponding to the partition $6=3+3$. Note that you specifically want all the partitions with $3$ in them (and no higher number, although $6$ is too small to allow that anyways). There are three of them, and they each give you one unique group.

Comment: For part 1 $g^|G| =e$ right? And $m$ is the smallest integer such that $g^m=e$. And now, by dividing, we get that $|G|=mq+r ,  and the  prove that r=0